# c++ creating ambigram from string

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I have a task to implement "void makeAmbigram(char*)" that will print on screen [ambigram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram) of latin string or return something like 'ambigram not possible'. Guess it's just about checking if string contains only of SNOXZHI and printing string backwards. Or am I wrong ?

I'm a complete noob when dealing with cpp so that's what I've created :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char[]words;
char[]reversed;

char[] ret_str(char* s)
{
    if(*s != '\0')
         ret_str(s+1);

    return s;
}

void makeAmbigram(char* c)
{
 /* finding chars XIHNOZS and printing ambigram */ 
}

int main()
{
   cin>>words;
   reversed = ret_str(words);
   makeAmbigram(reversed);
   return 0;
}
```

I can reverse string but how to check if my reversed string contains only needed chars ?
I've found some function but it's hard or even imposible to implement it for greater amount of chars : www.java2s.com/Code/C/String/Findcharacterinstringhowtousestrchr.htm

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.  Also, a definition of "ambigram" would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space in your arrays or use `std::vector`.  The arrays `word` and `reversed` are just pointers and no space is allocated.  The C++ language does not support dynamic arrays; however, the STL provides `std::vector` which dynamically allocates space as required.

**Change:**

```
char[]words;
char[]reversed;
```

**To:**

```
#define MAX_LETTERS 64
char words[MAX_LETTERS + 1]; // + 1 for terminating nul character ('\0')
char reversed[MAX_LETTERS + 1];
```

**Or:**

```
#include <string>
std::string words;
std::string reversed;
```

**Or:**

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<char> words;
std::vector<char> reversed;
```

As far as the ambigram rules go, you need to talk to your instructor.  Also, if this is homework, add a tag indicating so.

*Hint:  The `std::string` data type has some **reverse iterators** which may be of use to you.*

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has an entire family of member functions along the lines of [`find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/).  You can pass in a string containing all the letters your ambigram test requires, and they'll find whether any of those letters are present in the source string.

The complete list of string functions is available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Answer (score 0):

As for the definition of ambigrams, given the wiki page you've included in the question...you need to check if a letter is legible if viewed upside down, for eg. u/n, w/m, d/p, q/b and so on. There are of course more complex rules was well, for eg. 'ui' can resemble 'm' if viewed upside down.

However, if you're only required to check if your string contains only SNOXZHI, you can look into a regular expression (regex) for the same, and compare input string character-wise to your regex.